# What is the Intuition behind Lorentz Transformation of time?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, relative-motion

Suppose there are two spaceships, one at rest  and the other one moves at a constant relativistic speed.
 The spaceship at rest is going to observe an event occuring at distance $x_r$ from itsel and at a  time $t_r$, instead the spaceship will observe the same event at a distance $x_m$ and at a time $t_m$.

Let's say at time $t_m=0$ the moving spaceship observe a light flash at a distance $x_m$:
[image]

According to Loretnz, $t_r=\gamma t_m + \gamma v/c^2 x_m$ , so even if $t_m=0$ the spaceship at rest will still observe an event not occuring at the origin having a non-zero time.
What is the intuition behind this formula?
Why is it $\gamma v/c^2$?
Please note that I know the derivation of this formula, I'm looking for the intuition. I think it may be related to my precarious understanding of spacetime!

Comment: I think you're considering that both spaceships will receive the light spontaneously, so you're transforming the moving frame time into the rest frame time. When actually the spaceship at rest will receive the light at $t=x_r/c +t_0$ you can consider t0 the time they both synchronize their clocks and then see when each spaceship will receive the light. Or if you just transform the tm time to the rest frame now compare it to the time the rest spaceship will receive the light.

Comment: It's important to note that t_m and t_r are the time intervals elapsed since t_r=t_m=0 or when both spaceships where at the same time and space(x coordinate only). If t_m=0 gives a non zero reading of time coordinate for the rest spaceship it implies nothing more than that the clocks weren't synchronised at the beginning and the rest spaceships clock was ticking before the 'moving' ship started moving.

Comment: In the moment the spaceship moving is exactly above the one at rest,  2 different clocks on the two different ships start ticking and in the very same moment the light flash occurs according to the spaceship moving

Comment: You need to imagine that there are not just two clocks, but that there a whole team of observers in each frame strung out along the direction of relative motion.  Each observer is outfitted with a clock that has been synchronized with all the other clocks in his own frame of reference.  So, when an event occurs anywhere, there are observers from both frames present at the event to witness it.  These observers note not only the time on their own clock, but also the time on the clock of the observer present from the other frame.  This is how the time comparisons between frames  should be made.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your insight! If you try to condense the idea and the intuition in an answer, I will be glad to accept your answer as the most helpful @Chester Miller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to imagine that there are not just two clocks, but that there a whole team of observers in each frame strung out along the direction of relative motion. Each observer is outfitted with a clock that has been synchronized with all the other clocks in his own frame of reference. So, when an event occurs anywhere, there are observers from both frames present at the event to witness it. These observers note not only the time on their own clock, but also the time on the clock of the observer present from the other frame. This is how the time comparisons between frames should be made.

Comment: I got the idea, but I still don't get how is it possible that one can see time zero and another one a nonzero time...

Comment: The standard form of the Lorentz transformation assumes that there are a pair of observers in the two frames that are at the origins of each frame, and the event at which the two origins coincide occurs at t = 0, t'=0. This is the only event that shows the same time on the clocks of  any two juxtaposed observers from the two frames. The observers in each frame will argue that the clocks of the observers in the other frame are out of synchronization, even though all the clocks in each frame have been synchronized with one another. –